# Neo4j performance difference in using shell and API

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I understand that Neo4j supports different options to run the Cypher queries. The web browser, neo4j shell and the REST API. 
Is there a difference in performance when using the shell and the API?

I'm working on a dataset that has around 10 million objects(nodes+edges).

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your use-cases, cypher is usually good for 70-80%. For the rest it might make sense to write a server extension depending on performance. Make sure your queries are optimized feel free to ask with concrete examples.

Comment: @MichaelHunger thanks for your reply. Appreciate any feedback on some concrete examples given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104832/neo4j-improving-cypher-query-performance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web browser use in the backend the ReST API. The shell is connected directly into neo4j.

So yes you will see performance differences, the shell will generally be more faster. Now using the shell will perform slower that connecting to ReST API in your application because in the shell you can't pass parameters.

In your application, passing parameters will permit that the execution can be cached (after the warmup).

Also, if you have bad indexes and bad queries, running it on a 10 million objects dataset will just result in being not performant in the shell, in the browser and in your application.